# Project Euler 46 Solution Gives One Wrong Answer Along With the Right Answer

Tags: python, math

I wrote a solution to [PE #46](https://projecteuler.net/problem=46) which gives me two answers: 57 (wrong) and 5777 (right).  And I'm really struggling to figure out why!  I know it's not the most efficient code but if I could understand this, I could work on making it faster.  My `is_prime()` function is one I wrote for #7 and have used to solve several other problems, so I know (well, I'm confident ;) ) the issue isn't there, but I'm including it here for sake of completeness.

```py
from math import sqrt


def is_prime(x):
    if x % 2 == 0:
        return x == 2
    if x % 3 == 0:
        return x == 3

    step = 4
    m = int(sqrt(x)) + 1
    i = 5

    while i < m:
        if x % i == 0:
            return False
        step = 6 - step
        i += step

    return True


def is_composite(n):
    for x in range(2, n):
        for y in range(x, n):
            if x * y == n:
                return True
    return False


def test(n):
    for p in range(3, n):
        if is_prime(p):
            for t in range(1, p // 2):
                if p + (2 * t**2) == n:
                    return True
    return False


# currently this gives 57 (wrong) and also 5777 (right)                                                                                                                                                                                       
i = 33
while True:
    if is_composite(i):
        if not test(i):
            print(i)
    i += 2
```

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Here's the full text of the problem from the link above:

> It was proposed by Christian Goldbach that every odd composite number can be written as the sum of a prime and twice a square.
>
> 9 = 7 + 2×1^2
>
> 15 = 7 + 2×2^2
>
> 21 = 3 + 2×3^2
>
> 25 = 7 + 2×3^2
>
> 27 = 19 + 2×2^2
>
> 33 = 31 + 2×1^2
>
> It turns out that the conjecture was false.
>
> What is the smallest odd composite that cannot be written as the sum of a prime and twice a square?

Comment: You need to explain what problem you're actually trying to solve with this code and why 57 is wrong

Comment: @Sayse it's in the link I provided.  TBH I don't know why 57 is wrong, I just know that there's only one right answer and that one right answer is 5777 :(

Comment: Please actually include the information in the link in your post for self-containment.  We shouldn't have to go to an external link to help you with your problem.

Comment: 57 is wrong because 57=7+2*5^2. And I don't know python, but your `test` function looks wrong. I think you may have meant `n//2`, not `p//2`.

Comment: @Beta YES changing from `p//2` to `n//2` did the trick!  Thank you!  Time for me to do lots of debug printing so I can understand why :D

Comment: Also for anyone who finds this and has similar code: changing `is_composite()` to `def is_composite(n): return not is_prime(n)` will give you a HUGE speed boost.